# Focus a new ng-repeat element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-change

Using Angular, I want the user to be able to input into the main angular which will then (if the entry does not already exist) push a new 'action' into the 'actions[module.id].actions' array, thus creating a new input with ng-repeat, I then want to focus on that new input.

I am using 'addActionAction()' to add the new value to the array and then focus on the newly created input, however it seems the input is not actually created until after 'addActionAction()' has finished running so the input does not exist at the time I want to focus to it. Is there a way  around this?

```
     <div ng-repeat="(key, action) in actions[module.id].actions" >
      <span class="action-profile">{A{action}A}</span>
      <input id="action-input-{A{module.id}A}-{A{key}A}"type="text" ng-model="action">
    </div>

      <!-- main input-->
      <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.newActionText" ng-change="addActionAction()">
```

Function:

```
$scope.addActionAction= function()
  {
    if($scope.actions[$scope.selectedId].actions.indexOf($scope.newActionText) == -1)
    {
      $scope.actions[$scope.selectedId].actions.push($scope.newActionText);
      $scope.newActionText="";
      document.getElementById("action-input-"+$scope.selectedId+"-"+String(parseInt($scope.actions[$scope.selectedId].actions.length)-1)).focus();
    }

  };
```

Comment: wrap the focus call inside `$timeout()`

Comment: use `ng-focus='$last'`

Comment: @entre ng-focus seems to react to the element being focused rather than focusing on the element.

Comment: its add the focus attribute to the element which will have $last = true